# External js file is not detecting html table rows added via ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am retrieving data from SQL database and adding it as my existing HTML row.
Here is my code:

Ajax call to get data on `analyze_submit` submit

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#analyze_submit').click(function() {

   var data = $("#analyze_options_select").val();


     $.ajax({
            url  :ajaxurl,
            type :'POST',
            data: { 'action': 'expense','analyze_options':data },
            success: function(data){
                $("#example tbody").html(data);

            }
        });
            $("#summary_head").slideDown('slow');
            $("#detailed_view_head").slideDown('slow');
            $("#analyze_output").slideDown(); 

    }); 

});
```

Existing Table code:

```
<table id="example" class="grid">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Account</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

            </tbody>
</table>
```

I am adding the data in table `tbody` section.

Now I am trying to add sort\filter functionality for the final HTML table. For this, I need to call this external js file.

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

The problem I am facing is, this js file not detecting the data retrieved from the database through the ajax call.
I tried to add $.getScript at end of button submit function, but it's not working.

$.getScript('https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js);

I am new to jquery\javascript and currently stuck here. Any guidance to move forward?

Comment: ajax requests are ASYNCHRONOUS...

Comment: You might have to call some datatables function to update a datatable table

Comment: In your example you don't seem to be telling the dataTables plugin where to find your table, according to the plugin website, you need to define it as `$('#myTable').DataTable(); https://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
          "url"  :ajaxurl,
    } );
```

Comment: @giving me error "DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3"